# Firefox appears to drop word-wrap style when child's class is modified

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

Check this out:

```js
var iconIndex = 0;
  var icons = ['check', 'chain-broken', 'flag-o', 'ban', 'bell-o'];

  $('button:eq(0)').click(function() {
    iconIndex = (iconIndex + 1) % icons.length;
    $('#dev-0 .status-icon').attr('class', 'status-icon fa fa-fw fa-' + icons[iconIndex]);
  });
```

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.device-list-item {
  max-height: 31px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/css/tether.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="nav">
  <li id="dev-0">
    <a href="#" class="device-list-item">
      <span>
        <i class="status-icon fa fa-fw fa-bell-o"></i>
        <span>Firstwordhere Secondwordhere</span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<button>Click me</button>
```

*(Meh, apparently, something about the Snippets feature is actually triggering this even before you click the button. You can [see it on JSFiddle though](https://jsfiddle.net/bndmhn5t/3/))*

Clicking on the button should just cycle through icons, but *in Firefox only*<sup>†</sup> it also drops the "second word". It turns out that the word wrapping is changing, dropping the second word down onto an [invisible] second line. If I toggle the `word-break: break-all` property off then back on, using the debugger, the initial state is reclaimed.

What is causing this? Bad HTML/styles, or a Firefox bug?

And how can I work around it with a minimum of changes?

<sub><sup>†</sup> Broken in Firefox 50.1.0, 51.0.1; working in Chrome 55 and IE 11 (all Windows 7).</sub>

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: Really? You see _"Firstwordhere Secondw"_ in the box the whole time?

Comment: I have no idea what causing this problem in FF. But I did few css changes and think it looks its ok now- https://jsfiddle.net/bndmhn5t/4/

Comment: @JinuKurian: Now that is some dark arts

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yup it is. But guess we can find a better workaround with min css ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i would certainly classify this as a bug. You should report it in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org

Comment: Do you have CSS reset ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: FYI I think I've confirmed that. (See below)

Comment: @l2aelba: I don't think I know what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is [Firefox bug 1319424](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1319424), which is supposedly fixed in v53 (due April).

Indeed, it works as expected on nightly 53.0a2 (2017-02-09).